# Unable to locate package libqt4-core and libqt4-gui on Ubuntu 16

Tags: apt, 16.04

I am not an experienced user and I am having trouble installing Torch on my Ubuntu server. Apt is unable to find libqt4-core and -gui. I've read another thread saying to use dpkg but I cannot find the packages. Anybody there able to give me a detailed instruction on how to install those dependencies?

Comment: I think these packages are named `libqtcore4` and `libqtgui4`. So how about trying `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install libqtcore4 libqtgui4`?

Comment: @edwinksl You can post that as an answer here though it's simple. It's on-topic here.

Comment: @GokulNC Oh sure I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the packages you are looking for are named `libqtcore4` and `libqtgui4`. Therefore, do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libqtcore4 libqtgui4
```